# Add additional fields to select list on Webforms

Tags: 7, entities, webforms

In Webforms type field of Select options looks something like this:
[image]

But what if I need to add extra fields per each select option? Fields that are drop-down and you can select amount (number) of quantity.
[image]

So what it does is that user fills the form for a product query. They select products from the select list and select the quantity for each item. But how do you do that with Webforms?

Answer (score 1):

Had to create a fieldset per each select option with only one select option available and then just play around with CSS and it looks like one select list with separate quantity fields.